# How to find conf file of nginx running on linux machine with shell script

Tags: shell

I have used this **nginx -V 2>&1 | grep -o '--conf-path=(.conf)' | cut -d '=' -f2)** command.

I get this reply
**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

But I want it to come like this
**/etc/nginx**

Comment: `nginx -V 2>&1|grep -Po '(?<=--conf-path=).*?(?=/[^/]+(\s|$))'`

Comment: By the way, the command you provided does not produce the output you say it does. It outputs an error message. And even if you added `-e`, you still wouldn't get the output you say you do.